# ¿Se puede usar @property para una propiedad de clase?"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me pregunto si se puede hacer uso del decorador @ property en una propiedad de clase en python3.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede usar `@property` directamente para crear una propiedad de clase, pero si se sabe cómo funciona el protocolo "descriptor" en Python (es un asunto un poco complejo), se puede intentar implementar esa funcionalidad de una forma un tanto farragosa.

Supongamos que lo que quiero es tener una clase `C` que tenga una "propiedad de clase", llamémosla `dato`, de modo que yo pueda hacer `C.dato` y se ejecute una especie de *getter* que me dé el valor de ese atributo de clase `dato`, pero que esto también pueda funcionar para instancias. Es decir, que si hago `c = C()`, y luego `c.dato`, también se ejecute el mismo *getter* y me dé el valor del atributo de clase (que por tanto sería compartido por todos las instancias de esa clase).

Esto puede hacerse si escribimos previamente una clase que implemente el protocolo descriptor. La clase sería esta:

```
class classproperty:
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, type_=None):
        if not type_:
            type_ = type(obj)
        return self.getter(type_)
```

No voy a entrar en detalles de por qué esos nombre o por qué esos parámetros, pues es bastante farragoso y haría la respuesta, ya de por sí larga y compleja, aún más extensa.

El caso es que una vez tenemos la clase anterior, implementar la clase `C` deseada sería tan simple como:

```
class C:
    _dato = "Dato de la clase"

    @classproperty
    def dato(self):
        print("Ha sido llamado el getter")
        return self._dato
```

Podemos comprobar que se comporta como esperamos:

```
>>> C.dato
Ha sido llamado el getter
'Dato de la clase'
>>> instancia = C()
>>> instancia.dato
Ha sido llamado el getter
'Dato de la clase'
```

### Pero cuidado al cambiar

Si se intenta modificar el valor de `instancia.dato`, esto cambiará el valor de ese dato en la instancia, sin afectar a la propiedad de clase:

```
>>> d = C()
>>> e = C()
>>> d.dato
Ha sido llamado el getter
'Dato de la clase'
>>> d.dato = "Dato de instancia"
>>> d.dato
'Dato de instancia'
>>> e.dato
Ha sido llamado el getter
'Dato de la clase'
>>> C.dato
Ha sido llamado el getter
'Dato de la clase'
```

Hasta aquí todo normal. Lo mismo ocurriría con un atributo de clase. Pero el problema es que si intentamos modificar directamente `C.dato`, nada nos lo impide, se sobreescribe el atributo `dato` que era una propiedad y dejará ya de serlo (dejará de llamarse el getter al acceder):

```
>>> C.dato = "Dato de clase cambiado"
>>> C.dato
'Dato de clase cambiado'
>>> e.dato
'Dato de clase cambiado'
>>> d.dato
'Dato de instancia'
```

## Mejora

Podemos impedir que se pueda modificar la propiedad de clase, reimplementando el descriptor así:

```
class classproperty:
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter

    def __get__(self, obj, type_=None):
        if not type_:
            type_ = type(obj)
        return self.getter(type_)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError("No se puede modificar la propiedad de clase")
```

Con esto, un intento de hacer `C.dato = "otra cosa"` generará una excepción. Aunque lo mismo ocurrirá si se intenta cambiar el dato en una instancia, por lo que esto en el fondo creará una propiedad de solo lectura, definida en la clase y compartida por todas las instancias.

Answer (score 3):

Es largo de contar, pero cuando se accede al atributo de una instancia se sigue los pasos del llamado **protocolo descriptor** por el que se buscan *propiedades* en la clase.

Dicho de otro modo: las *propiedades* son atributos de clase, a pesar de que parezcan funcionar como atributos de la instancia. Para conseguir que una clase tenga propiedades hay que subir un nivel y usar las *metaclases* a partir de las que se crean las clases.

```py
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        dic["_x"] = 4
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)

    @property
    def number(cls):
        return cls._x

    @number.setter
    def number(cls, x):
        cls._x = 1

class C(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

print(C.number)
# 4

C.number = 6

print(C.number)
# 1
```

---

**Edición**:

Como comenta @abulafia, la propiedad de clase definida por la *metaclase* no es visible por las instancias de esa clase. Se podría conseguir manipulando el diccionario de la clase:

```py
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        dic["_x"] = 4
        dic["number"] = cls.number  # <-- línea añadida
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)

    @property
    def number(cls):
        return cls._x

    @number.setter
    def number(cls, x):
        cls._x = 1

class C(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

Comment: Interesante, pero si instancias `C()`, la instancia no tiene atributo `number` (aunque sea solo para lectura), como sí tendría si `number` fuera un atributo de clase normal. ¿Puede hacerse esto de algún modo?

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido alguna forma. Mira mi respuesta

Comment: No me gusta dar una respuesta genérica sin ver el caso concreto. Pero añado el caso que me comentas.